# How to Get World space coordinate from screen coordinates

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

How can we translate the Screen Space coordinate to World space coordinate.

1. in the below image the circle is drawn at position 0.0 , 0.0 , 0.0

[image]

Now if we move it to position -200 in x axis.

[image]

if we get the screen space vales by clicking on the centre point of the circle than the given values are (435 , 563)

From these values how can we get the value in world space which should be (-200.0 , 0.0 , 0.0 )

i tried following

```
 // Get View and Projection matrix
 glm::mat VP_Matrix = Projection * View;
 // Invert the matrix
 VP_Matrix = glm::Invert(VP_Matrix)
// Multiply it by Screen Space coordinate
glm::vec4 point = ( screen.x , screen.y , 0.0 , 1.0);
glm::vec4 finalPoint = VP_Matrix * point;


 // Final points 
 finalPoint.x /= finalPoint.w;
 finalPoint.y /= finalPoint.w;
```

But not able to get the correct points.

Comment: Can you raycast from the mouse click forward into the scene and check for an intersect with the circle / point of intersection?

Comment: I am not looking for intersection but just need the world space position of the mouse click.

Comment: It is not possible in the 3D space. In the 3D space you can only have ray and then you can calculate intersection like @jackw11111 wrote.

Comment: @Raffallo I have managed to get the point using  glm::vec3 posVec = glm::unProject(
    glm::vec3(p.x, float(1080) - p.y, 1.0f),
    glm::mat4(1.0f),
    projection,
    glm::vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, float(1920), float(1080))
   ); , where z is 0.0

Comment: But Still interested in knowing the Maths behind it